# OS X - How to read data from S.M.A.R.T.?

Tags: c, macos

I want to access to information regarding the hard drive - for example the temperature.
How can I do this, preferably in C?

Comment: Have you looked at the source code for smartmontools http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki

Comment: Just read the API documentation and go for it...

Comment: Why was this closed? It was a programming question, showing little effort, but sometimes it's difficult to find source code using Google. It was more interesting than many of the "what does this program do?", "what is a variable?" questions that do not get closed and are becoming majority on SO. And, by the way, Adrian's comment was a perfectly fine answer.

Comment: "Not a real question"? Ambiguous? Vague? This is where some interesting questions go thanks to incompetent people uselessly closing stuff here and there. Thank you.

Comment: @Adrian Cornish Thank you for your answer, that has been helpful.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/  link now down